# UNION together with the WHERE statement

Tags: ms-access

Almost there, I created  a UNION together with an LEFT JOIN, and a RIGHT JOIN and WHERE statement.

```
SELECT Table1.FName, Table1.Path, [Table2].Filename, [Table2].STORE_LOC
FROM [Table2] RIGHT JOIN Files ON [Table2].[Path] = Table1.[Path]
WHERE ((Table1.FName) LIKE "*.PDF")
UNION
SELECT Table1.FName, Table1.Path, [Table2].Filename, [Table2].STORE_LOC
FROM [Table2] LEFT JOIN Files ON [Table2].[Path] = Table1.[Path]
WHERE ((Table1.FName) LIKE "*.PDF");
```

Table1 is generated  and is a file list, Table2 is the metadata. This SQL works fine, but when I changed the WHERE statement to:

```
WHERE (((Table1.FName) Like Forms!Frm_File_Search!text2)
```

It doesnot work anymore. I want to use the values in my text box togetter with this query. Does anyone have a clue??? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. check that there are 3 '('  and only 2 ')' in your Q.
2. Try to do such workaround:
   replace

   Forms!Frm_File_Search!text2

with

```
eval("Forms!Frm_File_Search!text2")
```

Comment: Thanks!!!, spent 8 hours yesterday and my desperation was growing. Found the problem, one space too much. It works, but only when I restrict my WHERE statement to values of Table1, If I add also values from Table2 you see only the records which are common. Is there a way to use one query with values form both tables? In general, I want to see all my records and want to use several text boxes as filters. Anyone?

Comment: i don't understand your comment, but may be use of `UNION ALL` will show all records not only distinct. And you can use as many text boxes as you need.

Comment: My first table has 100000 records, my second table with the metadata contains 50000 records, when I add textboxes as filters from table1 it works fine, still 100000 records (when I use "*" as value). When I add text boxes from both tables as filters, I have a problem, I see only 50000 records. Any help is welcome!

Comment: SELECT Table1.FName, Table1.Path, Table2.Path, Table2.STORE_LOC
FROM Table2 RIGHT JOIN Files ON Table2.Path = Table1.Path
WHERE (((Table1.FName) Like Forms!Frm_File_Search!text2));

Nice 100000 records (Values are "*") Now I add a Column from the second table

SELECT Table1.FName, Table1.Path, [Table2].Path, Table2.STORE_LOC
FROM Table2 RIGHT JOIN Files ON Table2.Path = Table1.[Path]
WHERE (((Table1.FName) Like Forms!Frm_File_Search!text2) AND ((Table2.STORE_LOC) Like Forms!Frm_File_Search!text8));

problem  50000 records (Values are "*")